# Incorporate rows without creating dimension and graph

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I want to get the next result https://jsfiddle.net/ajey2987/0bqjydx8/26/,
 without the need to create a other dimension, group and graph, ie, without region2dim and numxregion2 and function reflect_filters.

```
var regiondim = ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.Region;});
var regiondim2= ndx.dimension(function(d){return d.Region;});
var numxregion=regiondim.group(); 
var numxregion2=regiondim2.group();
```

Is this possible?

I want to click on the names of the regions, they are incorporated one by one and recalcule the percentage based on the selected data.

regards

Thank you so much

Comment: Groups and dimensions update automatically after `dimension.filter` calls. Just query the group again using `group.top` or `group.all` and you will get the updated aggregates. Note though: https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/Crossfilter-Gotchas#a-group-does-not-observe-its-dimensions-filters

Comment: That idea allow me to remove regiondim2 and numxregion2, and get the same interactive graph?

Comment: In the linked example you are only rendering one chart, so yes. But I suspect you are going for something else. Can you explain more what you would like to see vs what you are seeing?

Comment: My English is not very good.
I want a graphic, in which they will be showing the bars of the regions when I click on the name. And recalculate the percentage based on the selected regions when clicking. For example, if I select a region I want it to say 100% and the other regions the bar does not appear and its percentages are 0%. If I select two regions, I want to calculate the percentage of only the two as a function of the total given by the two regions, and so on.
It is understood?

Comment: No problem on the English. With only a single chart there will be no way you can select 2 regions, so I'm assuming you want to use 1 chart for selection and the other to show the %s. Is this example what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/f4yqu8zo/

Comment: No, I want the same result in https://jsfiddle.net/ajey2987/0bqjydx8/26/, but to get to that result I had to create dimregion2, numxregion2 and create the barra-region2 graphic to be able to apply the reflect_filters function. Creating dimregion2 (which is the new dimension) is very expensive computationally. Is it possible to obtain the barra-region graph (only a graph) with the dimregion and numxregion and that the bars are included by clicking on the names of the regions, if I select by Example A and B be 80% and 20% (this based on the data) and so on?

Comment: Got it - you are clicking on the labels to do multiple selections. I've got a working example now and will write you an answer quickly :-) Here's the example: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/f4yqu8zo/1/

Comment: By the way, I would not say that creating dimregion2 is computationally expensive. It is just created once (which does cost some computation) and will not require very much additional computation on filtering at all. But if you are seeing performance problems with this approach, let's look at that, perhaps in a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key insight here is that groups do not observer filters on their own dimensions, so what you'll need to do is create 2 dimensions and set the dc.js chart to use a dimension and group that are not linked. Because the % calculation also depends on a `groupAll` group that needs to be not linked to the filter dimension, you'll want to create this group on the 2nd dimension as well.

So your dimension and group definitions would look like this:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(datos);
var regiondim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return '' + d.Region;
});
var regiondim2 = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
  return '' + d.Region;
});
var numxregion2 = regiondim2.group();
var countgroup = regiondim2.groupAll().reduceCount()
```

And your dc.js chart definition would look something like this (based on your example, with formatting removed):

```
barraxregion
  .dimension(regiondim)
  .group(numxregion2)
  .title(function(d) {
    return d.value + " (" + (d.value / countgroup.value() * 100).toFixed(1) + "%)"
  })
```

The title is showing both a value and the overall % based on the previously defined `countgroup`.

Working version of the example: https://jsfiddle.net/esjewett/f4yqu8zo/1/

Comment: thank you very much! But is it necessary the two dimensions?

Comment: But is it necessary the two dimensions?

Comment: Yes, I think it is. Dimensions are quite cheap in Crossfilter. I don't think you should see much impact on performance, if you see any at all.

Comment: Again, I appreciate your help and patience.